Rust match on generic optional
I'm handling different messages, each handle function will return an Optional which is serializable by serde or None.
If a response is not None, i want to send it through the sender
The let response: Option<T impl Serialize> - Is not valid rust, just trying to make a point that the return value of the match is serializable.
Trying to figure out a clean way to match the response into a variable, based on the fact it extends Serializable. Can't find the rust way the actually compiles :)
pub fn handle_status_notification(charge_point: &ChargePoint,
                                  boot_notification: StatusNotificationRequest) -> Option<StatusNotificationResponse> {
    if error {
        return None;
    }
    
    let response = StatusNotificationResponse {

    };

    Some(response)
}


let response: Option<T impl Serialize> = match action.as_str() {
    "BootNotification" => {
        handle_boot_notification(&charge_point, payload)
    }

    "StatusNotification" => {
        handle_status_notification(&charge_point, payload)
    }

    _ => {
        println!("Received unknown action: {}", action);
        None
    }
};

if let Some(payload) = response {
    sender.send(Message::Text(create_response(3, &message_id, payload)))
}


Have a look at the erased_serde crate. This provides an object-safe Serialize trait, so you can box both values into a Box<dyn erased_serde::Serialize>.

Alternatively, use an untagged enum: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c79c166ab3faccea98893498352997fc

thanks @FinnBear - tagged enum works well.

In this use case it is also possible to monomorphize the call sender.send into each match case, thus evading the need for a response variable. Other than that, the given duplicate target is valid and offers solutions to scenarios where we definitely need a variable or a function return type as a sink point for different types.
